# lua simple regexp issue

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to learn how to use regexps in lua but I see no results, so I'm asking for help.

I got two types of url:

```
1) /a/b/c/d/some,text,commas,and,so,on,FILE.dat 
2) /a/b/c/d/FILE.dat
```

I need to do two things:

1. get substring with filename: `FILE.dat`
2. get substring with path: `/a/b/c/d/FILE.dat`

I have written regex which retrieves me a filename from a first case:

```
string.match(url, ".*,(.*)")
```

similar regex retrives me a filename from second case:

```
string.match(url, ".*/(.*)")
```

Now can You tell me, how to merge this two regexs into one?

Comment: Lua doesn't have regexes, it has some pattern matching, which is a lot more limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those two cases are your only ones, matching for the filename is easy starting from the back:

```
filename=string.match(url,'([%w_]+%.%w%w%w)$')
```

For tossing out the comma separated part I'd resort to something like

```
filepath=string.gsub(url,'%w+,', '')
```